# Return an array of ints containing the number of elements of each inner array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, element

I want to write a function which, given an array of arrays of integers in input, returns an array of integers in output, containing the number of elements of each inner array.

This is my current implementation:

```
public static int[] countEach(int[][] a) {
    int[] count = new int[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++){
      count[i] = a[i].Length;
    }
    return count;
}

public static void Main(string[] args){
  int[][] a = new int[][]{
    new int[] {1, 2, 3},
    new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    new int[] {1}
  };
  int[] result = countEach(a);
}
```

It works, however i dont want to define a fixed length of 3 beforehand. So how do i rewrite this so that it can take any input array? I cant think of any, and is there a better way to code this? So i can better grasp the programming concepts of c#. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int[] countEach(int[][] a) {
    int[] count = new int[a.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++){
      count[i] = a[i].Length;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq, by Selecting length of nested arrays and call `.ToArray()` to convert `IEnumerable` to `array` :

```
int[] result = a.Select(x => x.Length).ToArray();
```

Namespace :

```
using System.Linq;
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: i should have said without the use of any libraries, but thanks

Comment: @user3660293 That's built into .Net.

Comment: @user3660293 just add the namespace `using System.Linq;`

Comment: and without any additional namespaces *